# I want to add an event listener to an element which gets fired when the corresponding elements is scrolled into the view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I add such an event listener to an element? My motive is to highlight elements in nav bar when the page is scrolled into the corresponding section. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a plugin i used several times which fit you needs:

[JQuery Inview](https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview)

or

[Viewport Selectors](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport)